# How to create object of Collection and add elements to it

Tags: java, collections

How to create an object of Collection and add elements to it?

I did something like this :

```
Collection col = Collections.EmptyList();
col.add("String1");
```

But its throwing UnsupoortedOperationException because EmptyList() will create an immutable object which can't be changed.

Answer (score 2):

`Collection` is just the interface for objects that store other objects. You must instantiate it with an actual implementation like a HashSet. For example:

```
Collection<String> col = new HashSet<String>();
col.add("String1");
```

Note that you must also provide the type of the object that you want to store, like `String`, `List` or `Object`. See [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) for more infos.

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.EmptyList()` creates an empty list in which you cannot add more objects.
you have to create by specifying type of list like :

```
Collection<String> col = new ArrayList<String>();
col.add("String1");
```

Answer (score 0):

you should specify type of collection.

try in this way

```
1.Collection<String> col = new Arraylist<>();
         col.add("String1"); 

   2.List<String> col = new ArrayList<>();
      col.add("String1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Collection is not a concrete Object class it is just a interface, you have to create any collection concrete class that implements Collection interface like HashSet, ArrayList etc.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Collection col = new ArrayList<>();
        col.add("String1");
        System.out.println(col.toString());
    }
```

Comment: You are defining a raw type Collection which is discourage

Comment: thats ok if you dont want to give specification to the class